# Delay Kubernetes Deployment from Python Client

Tags: python, django, multithreading, kubernetes, delayed-execution

I have a Django software that, using [Kubernetes Official Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) to interface with my kubernetes cluster for pods deploying. These pods are dockerized Scala SBT apps, and as soon as I launch them all together, it takes a lot of time to compile.

Putting some time.sleep() will actually optimize the releases, but it will also delay the response.. And i have to avoid this.

I'm trying to see about multiprocessing and actually works on a test file, which is:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def test1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("before test1: " + str(time.time()))
    time.sleep(3)
    print("after test1: " + str(time.time()))


def test2():
    print("before test2: " + str(time.time()))
    time.sleep(4)
    print("after test2: " + str(time.time()))


def main():
    print(time.time())
    pool = Pool()
    result1 = pool.apply_async(test1)
    result2 = pool.apply_async(test2)

    result1.get()
    result2.get()


main()
```

Infact, the "after test1" and "after test2" will be executed at the same time. But when i transfer these statements where it's needed, it stops parallelizing. the structure of the test file is the same of where i need it. a def with the pool instanciating defs inside, and a sleep inside these defs, all inside an @api_view. I also tried using other libraries, like threading, asyncio etc.. all worked fine in the test file.

I was also seeing i can put a sleep in the Dockerfile, but I also saw the raise of some problems in the same thread.

So my question is, is there some sort of native setting that I can give when creating a V1Container object? How can i delay the pods release without delaying the response time?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I noticed that even with the test file i will obtain a response only after terminating the operations... even if it does parallelize the operations. maybe is exactly the return of the response that can't allow me to delay? should i make another django app for that?

Comment: Can you compile the applications ahead of time, and deploy images that only contain built jar files?  What happens if you just deploy everything at once, and then wait a while for all of the deployments to come up?

Comment: @DavidMaze the problem is that the sbt compile is heavy, and if there are two sbt run at the same time, the compile will take triple the time. i sincerely didn't understand your advice, sorry :(